# Oauth error in deploying Shopify Private App

Tags: shopify

I am trying to write a Shopify private app.  I have watched the Kevin Hughes appinfive video (several times) and carefully followed all the steps but when I get to the end, when I try to install the application, I get this error:

> Oauth error invalid_request: The Shopify API application does not support oauth

Any possibility for help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Private apps can't be embedded, you'll need to create an app through your partner dashboard (like Kevin does in the video) to use OAuth.